# Multi-user form/noting software for following checklists

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I have recently been promoted to manage a PC repair shop. I was a lead tech, but now manage. For many jobs we follow (flexible) checklists. For example there may be a 26-point disenfection protocol where step 5 is to mount the drive in a clean shop PC and scan it with MBAM and EEK, storing logs and recording results and peculiarities on the worksheet.

The previous manager was very old school, and the current procedure is to print the sheet and keep it with the job. Any tech can then look at the sheet and pick up where ever that job is. At the conclusion of a job, the data is manually entered as notes in a textarea field in our web based ticket system (or attached as a file attachment to the ticket). A paper copy was kept filed as well. I want to move us away from that system. There are many reasons for this, including reducing errors and time in reentering the notes as well as reducing paper consumption.

The ideal solution would be web-based and/or mobile friendly. This way the checklists could be followed, and notes taken on tablets, phones, netbooks etc. One simply has to look up a particular job to find its progress. Also, at the completion of the job it should be easy to export or copy and paste the completed worksheet back to our ticketing system.

The ticketing system is **PacketTrap**, and it has an API, but currently it does not look easy to accomplish what I need.  No one here currently has the knowledge or time to deeply modify that system.

I have some web devel skills, but not much and I am slow at that. I have investigated using **Drupal** with custom fields and content types. I have also looked at using forms and templates in **MediaWiki** as a kludge. Neither seems optimal. Both because of the time involved, and because of state maintenance issues. For example, if a tech starts a new job based on a content type or template, that entered data exists only in his/her browser until saved, preventing other techs from easily continuing the service using a separate device to follow along.

**Google Forms** seems close, except that it dumps form results in a spreadsheet that would need some sort of massaging before adding to a service ticket at job completion. **Google Docs**, and **MS Word** for Android do not allow easily adding a picture to the document. This is not a huge issue, but it would be nice to be able to attach pictures of physical damage, or issues like BSoDs that cannot easily have a screenshot taken. Unfortunately, neither app will easily take a pic with the device attached camera.

So basically, does anyone have a suggestion for a system, either mobile and cloud based, or just basic web-based, that will allow me to create form templates, allow users to create a new form based off of the template, possibly insert images, and maintain state of the form as it is entered?

Comment: Without going in to much detail, I think JIRA would be a great solution for you. (Confluence also provides a Sharepoint-like documentation alternative which could be used for other useful things)

Jira can be found here: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira

It's cheap for 10 or fewer users and super easy to set up.

That being said, there may be a better StackExchange site for this question.

Comment: You can use MediaWiki with SemanticForms. To "easily continue", just save the page and let the next user open the form-edit view from where the form was left.